# MySQL sorting by 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to create a sort of menu system with the following structure and sort the contents accordingly.

```
+----+-------+----------+
| id | title | parentid |
+----+-------+----------+
| 1  | a     | 0        |
| 2  | b     | 0        |
| 3  | c     | 0        |
| 4  | aa    | 1        |
| 5  | ab    | 1        |
| 6  | ca    | 3        |
+----+-------+----------+
```

I would like to sort them like the following however I can not find or come up with a union or a sort by query that will work.

```
+----+-------+----------+
| id | title | parentid |
+----+-------+----------+
| 1  | a     | 0        |
| 4  | aa    | 1        |
| 5  | ab    | 1        |
| 2  | b     | 0        |
| 3  | c     | 0        |
| 6  | ca    | 3        |
+----+-------+----------+
```

Comment: It looks to me like you mean ORDER BY, not GROUP BY. I also have no idea which two of the three columns you want to do the ordering by.

Comment: I think the "title", dictionary-order?

Comment: Sorry I am trying to group by the parentid and id. All values are test values to try and make my point more clear in how they are related.

Comment: from the result u want, u can simply sort it using title column

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're really asking for is to order your tree by parent id.

This is a rather complex thing to do, although we do it at work, so I'll show you what we do. Although we use PostgreSQL, so you'll undoubtedly need to adapt this to MySQL. But hopefully it will point you in the right direction.

We use this data structure for our **uids** table"

```
                          Table "public.uids"
   Column   |            Type             |              Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------
 uid        | integer                     | not null default 
 name       | character varying(64)       | not null
 parent     | integer                     |
```

And we have an auxiliary table which we unfortunately call **uid_cache**, which looks like this:

```
          Table "public.uid_cache"
 Column |   Type   | Modifiers | Description 
--------+----------+-----------+-------------
 uid    | integer  | not null  | 
 parent | integer  | not null  | 
 level  | smallint | not null  |
```

This table is kept up-to-date with INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE triggers on the main **uids** table.  The trigger does many other things that are very specific to our application, and it's long and unwieldy, so I won't post it here.  But this auxiliary table contains one row for every uid/parent relationship that exists on the system, and **level** shows how many steps there are between each.

So for instance, if our **uids** table contains:

```
 uid | parent 
-----+--------
   0 |       
   1 |      0
   2 |      1
   3 |      1
```

(uid 0 has no parent, it is *the* master parent uid)

Then our **uid_cache** table contains:

```
 uid | parent | level 
-----+--------+-------
   0 |      0 |     0
   1 |      1 |     0
   1 |      0 |     1
   2 |      2 |     0
   2 |      1 |     1
   2 |      0 |     2
   3 |      3 |     0
   3 |      1 |     1
   3 |      0 |     2
(8 rows)
```

With this table, it's easy to tell at a glance the "distance" between any two uids.  3's distance from it's parent 0 is 2 steps. 3's distance from it's parent 1 is 1 step.  And 3's distance from itself is, well, 0 steps. (You may or may not want to record the uid's relationship with itself, depending on your application--it's useful in our case)

Now, with these two tables, we can create this stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uid_tree(INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER[] AS $$
    SELECT ARRAY(SELECT parent FROM uid_cache WHERE uid = $1 ORDER BY level DESC)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE STRICT;
```

Then with this function, we can do:

```
SELECT uid,parent,uid_tree(uid)
FROM uids
ORDER BY uid_tree(uid);
```

And we get:

```
 uid | parent | uid_tree 
-----+--------+----------
   0 |        | {0}
   1 |      0 | {0,1}
   2 |      1 | {0,1,2}
   3 |      1 | {0,1,3}
(4 rows)
```

I'm pretty sure this is the answer you are looking for.  I also have a high suspicion it's far more involved than you were hoping for!

Please let me know if I can clarify anything for you.

Comment: Sorry I am trying to group by the `parentid` which refers to the `id`

Comment: You're trying to group, or sort?  These are entirely different operations.

Comment: Yes sort, I suppose group was the wrong term for this instance.

Comment: Okay, I've updated your question. Does my answer actually answer your needs, or is there more?

Comment: Thank you for updating the question but your answer does not fully answer what i'm asking. The title is irrelevant I included that to make it easier to look at. the parentid refers to a corresponding id in the same table and I am trying to have them sorted by that link. A parentid of 0 means they are pointing to the root or are as high as they get if you want to look at it that way.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do now... you're trying to order by the id-tree.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm modifying an existing system that was setup In trying to find the most efficient way to doing this i was going from the bottom up to avoid a N^2 runtime but it seems i'll have to accept that to keep from disturbing the integrity. 
`select * from table where parentid>0`
Then for each row result
`select * from table where parentid=$id`

Comment: There may be other answers out there. I suspect they won't be as efficient, but they might be easier. Maybe someone else will answer, too.